# PHP inserts escape sequence for double quotes when i GET a string containing HTML contents

Tags: php, html

I am generating a HTML code using JavaScript and passes it to PHP code using a get method. Now when I try to `echo` the HTML content, the HTML contains double quotes with an escape sequence to this the code HTML doesn’t run. Is there a way or function in PHP which can help me get rid of these double quotes.

Sample code....
 my input is this

Input: `<div id="test"></div>`....

php code that i use to receive the content is...

```
<?php
$str=$_GET["send"];
$str1 = htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $str1;
?>
```

Output is this `<div id=\"test\"></div>`

Comment: As always, show your code. That being said, you may be looking for [stripslashes()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). They are a deprecated feature that was removed in PHP 5.4.

The best way to remove them is to *upgrade to a modern version of PHP* (preferably the 5.5 branch).

Failing that, you can [configure PHP to not use them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).